# How to rename "/admin" to other URL in web2py?

Tags: python, web-applications, web2py

web2py application administration is by default located on:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/default/site
```

Is it possible to change "admin" to be something else (for example):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/appadmin/default/site
```

and if it is possible how that is achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

admin is just an app.

On windows open windows explorer and go to \web2py\applications\ right click on "admin" folder an then click in rename.

On Linux.

```
cd path/to/web2py/applications
mv admin newadmin
```

Comment: i'm on mac, will check how this suggestion works and will come back, recipe on mac is a bit different (whole thing is in .app bundle), but I can find my way around :) Thank you for the explanation of the approach.

Comment: works like a charm! :) Many thanks!
Mac users shall examine web2py.app, within app package, `Resources/applications`
(note: default 'administration' links on builtin pages will obviously be broken after intervention)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12487174/4065350) is correct, but more changes needs to be done.

In your case, to change url from `/admin` to `/appadmin` do following steps

1. Rename `admin` app folder name to `appadmin`
2. Fix broken links to admin app

   In `your_app/controllers/appadmin.py`, search all links to `admin` app and replace it with links to `appadmin` app
3. Change creation of links to error pages

   Update `routes.py`, to route errors to `appadmin` app and not `admin` app

For detailed steps read [How to change admin app url in web2py?](http://gauravvichare.com/how-to-change-admin-app-url-in-web2py/)